# How to provide meanings (metadata) of attributes/fields with shapefiles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, attribute-table, metadata

Usually when doing GIS projects, especially when working as a freelancer, you're just provided with a bunch of shapefiles and you have to figure out yourself what all the table attributes mean. Because shapefiles have a *.dbf limited character number for naming attribute fields, the names are usually abbreviations. Is there a way to add a description of the attribute field names when creating them, or how do you add attribute field metadata. What do you do when you don't understand the abbreviations of a shapefile attribute table metadata that has been created by someone else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just did a quick test of creating a shapefile and then used **ArcMap 10.2** to access the **Metadata** tab of **Customize | ArcMap Options** where I set the Metadata Style to **ISO 19139 Metadata Implementation Specification** (but the other choices are likely to behave similarly).

In the **Catalog** window I accessed the **Item Description** of the shapefile and clicked **Edit** to start editing its metadata.  In the **Resource** section in the lefthand panel I found **Fields** and when I opened one of the fields in the righthand panel I found a **Definition** type-in area that looks like what you are after.

When the shapefile provider **Save**s the metadata it gets written to an XML file called **.shp.xml** that gets copied with the remainder of the shapefile so you should be able to open it up in **Item Description**.

[image]